# someone votes down against my question - should I do something about it?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

One of these days I have posted the following question:

[Unable to create a Filtered Index on a Computed Column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116347/unable-to-create-a-filtered-index-on-a-computed-column)

which someone decided to downvote. I had a look at the question, and I cannot find anything wrong with it.

Maybe is it because I linked it with another question of mine?
Is it not correct according to the rules?

I think the question is clear, it is not offensive, ok I might not be perfect in my language but whoever has downvoted me, if they at least explain the reason they did so I could try to see things in their way and perhaps change the question.

what is the standard way to proceed in this situation?

Comment: If the question is good (it has three upvotes, too), just don't care.  If you get a comment pointing to a deficiency, fix that.  And don't think that this type of comment necessarily comes from a downvoter.  Oh, and I see absolutely no problem with that link - the questions seem to be a complete one even without it.

Comment: The question seems good. The only that might be missing - although it's rather obvious what you are after - is a specific question at the end, something like *"(How) can I create a filtered index on a computed column?"* or *"Is there an alternative solution"*.

Comment: There are various kinds of people on this network so different ways of looking at a question and reading it. Someone might have not found your question sutable as per his standard or *something other* and so must have downvoted. Relax this happens to everybody

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have done everything you should. It is perfectly correct to ask a follow-up question. Upon receiving a down-vote, you have checked the question is as clear and as good as you can make it, and finally asked on meta to ask if anyone else can see why it might have attracted a down-vote.

People vote for all sorts of reasons, and do so anonymously. Not even moderators can see who voted for what and when. For all anyone knows, the voter hit the wrong voting direction arrow, just didn't like your avatar, or had just burnt his or her toast that morning. There's really no way to know, since they chose not to leave a comment (as is their prerogative).

The system does [gently try to encourage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) comments on down-votes, but leaving a comment yourself to ask for a reason [is definitely discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74559/is-it-now-discouraged-to-ask-for-reasons-for-downvotes-as-a-comment).

There is no further corrective action you can take, so I would encourage you to put it down to a mistake, or factors outside of your control, and move on. For what it's worth, I up-voted your question, as both clear and useful.

---

See also (originally a comment on the question by [Andriy M](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6965/andriy-m)):

- [I've just been downvoted. How should I react?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react) - meta.SE

Comment: My personal view is that a down-vote should give a reason. A colleague deleted a question, gaining a Peer Pressure badge, as it seemed that after a few down-votes people were cruising by and down-voting. At that stage he had not received any type of answer bar a comment on a spelling error!

Comment: @MichaelJohn I could not agree more but you cannot make it compulsory. Sometimes the questions are so *unclear* you just down vote it and leave no comments as somebody has already penned down your thoughts.

Comment: @MichaelJohn The majority of the community [disagrees with you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) (myself included, though I did once share your opinion). Having read that entire discussion multiple times, I've since changed my tune. The biggest reason is that you can force people to tick some box or fill in some minimum number of characters, but you can't force them to be honest, prevent them from typing gibberish, or avoid vengeful behavior when they are honest.